# Scrape race results page with R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I did a race where they only present your results, but I'd like to see how I compare to the others. I've done this for other races, and usually results are presented in a table, but this one seems different. I'm not sure where to start, maybe some people can point me in the right direction, preferably with R.

This is the link to the results of the winning athlete. I would like to get:
Name, country, BIB and all the times.

https://results.sporthive.com/events/6577137678160433152/races/465951/bib/10

Where should I look? I've used rvest before, but that doesn't seem to do the trick here. There doesn't seem to be an HTMLtable involved.

The following runs without error, but returns an empty table:

```
tables <- GET("https://results.sporthive.com/events/6577137678160433152/races/465951/bib/10") 
result <- readHTMLTable(rawToChar(tables$content))
```

When using I'm not seeing any nodes I can access (following the link from Simon:

```
my_session <- html_session("https://results.sporthive.com/events/6577137678160433152/races/465952/bib/10")
```

Update: The following returns a list with elements, which contain the data I want.

```
library(RSelenium)

  # start the server and browser(you can use other browsers here)
  rD <- rsDriver(browser=c("firefox"))
  driver <- rD$client

  driver$navigate("https://results.sporthive.com/events/6577137678160433152/races/465952/bib/2404")

  elements <- driver$findElements(using = "css",".ng-binding") 

#  Use apply functions to extract elements:
    texts_lapply <- lapply(elements,function(x) x$getElementText()[[1]])
```

Comment: Could you please share your current coding attempt and indicate what is happening versus what should.

Comment: https://github.com/yusuzech/r-web-scraping-cheat-sheet

Comment: Usually I would use GET and readHTMLTable to get a table with the contents. This doesn't throw any errors and runs, but it returns an empty table.

Comment: @QHarr Something like this: tables <- GET("https://results.sporthive.com/events/6577137678160433152/races/465952/bib/2404")
result <- readHTMLTable(rawToChar(tables$content))

Comment: Hi @egilio, thanks for responding. You can use [edit] to add this info to the question.

Comment: Also, could you mock up desired output format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this data comes from an API call you can find in the browser network tab when pressing F5 to refresh the page. You get json response you can parse whatever you want from

```
library(jsonlite)

data <- jsonlite::read_json('https://eventresults-api.sporthive.com/api/events/6577137678160433152/races/465951/bib/10')

print(data$fullClassification$athlete$name)
print(data$fullClassification$classification)
```